# Where to securely place files needed by PHP in Linux filesystem (according to FHS)

Tags: php, apache-httpd, fhs

I have a PHP script running on my LAMP server that requires certain files in order to produce HTML content. The script is publicly accessible (i.e. `http://example.com/script.php`) but the files required by the script must secured. I could probably place the files in any directory other than `/var/www` and they would be relatively safe, but I'm trying to learn the Linux filesystem and I'd like to use the most *appropriate* place (according to FHS). Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `/var/www`, create a folder public_html and reconfigure that as your root directory for Apache. Files in `/var/www` can be included, but not accessed directly.